# Making Jquery Cycle work within a dynamic xhtml layout

Tags: jquery, resize, slideshow, cycle, jquery-cycle

Hello I'm trying to run a javascript resize for my page using the [Particle tree method](http://particletree.com/features/dynamic-resolution-dependent-layouts/)
- whenever the window resolution changes a different css stylesheet is called.

In each stylesheet (default.css/thin.css/wide.css/wider.css) I have changed the dimensions of the cycle slideshow and dimensions of the images.

[Previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183869/problem-trying-to-do-window-resize-with-jquery-cycle-slideshow) suggest Cycle stores the elements width and height once. I have tried to  fix the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('.slideshow')  
.after('<div id="nav">')  
.cycle({  
        fx: 'fade',  
        sync: true,  
                speedIn:  500,  
        speedOut:  500,  
        timeout: 10000,  
        pager:  '#nav',  
        next:   '.slideshow'  
                cssBefore: {  
                width: imagewidth,    
                height: imageheight  
}    

    });
});
```

This doesn't work for me... I have also tried containerResize: false; is this a case of assigning ! important rules into the css stylesheets?

Thanks for any help! Full website code [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8847353/Jai_Sandhu_Design_Portfolio/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your target browsers, you may be able to do the same with media queries (responsive design). By specifying the dimensions in the CSS, different styles are applied. See 
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/ for details.

Comment: Thanks that is an easier way to create flexible images using css instead of javascript. I can easily implement this with images but my main issue is with the Cycle slideshow, getting that to scale is a little more tricky. The height and width value gets stored and does not adapt, I think I need to modify the Cycle options so this doesn't happen... Any suggestions for this?