# Jquery cycle - auto resizing images on changing browser window

Tags: jquery, cycle, autoresize

Afternoon all..

I have a site with an intro page including a jquery cycle slideshow of three images.

I have set up the CSS so that the images resize in accordance with the browser window.

This all works fine when the images are on their own, however when they are part of the slideshow I have to refresh the screen to make the images fit properly. They do actually still resize properly, just not automatically with a manual change in window size as they do when on their own.

The Url is - http://subzerostudio.com/Clients/ex1/index.html -

You can see that if you bring the window size down and leave it during the slideshow the images are the correct size, and the same if the window size is full, the images still fit - it is just when resizing the window they remain the previous height and width that was initially loaded.

They are also set up to be flexible in terms of position in order to fit different resolutions to a certain extent however this aspect is fine.

Once this is sorted it's ready to go out :) any ideas are much appreciated!

Chris

Comment: Check out the resize method of jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Hi Baszz thanks for this! I've looked through and am not totally sure how to integrate this, can you point out how I'd get this talking to the slideshow?

Comment: I don't know the slideshow code so I cannot help you with that. I think you should implement the resize method and set some variables or something that are being used by the slideshow. Or maybe re-initialize the slideshow on resize...something like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Baszz - I've found a solution in case anyone else gets stuck on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183869/problem-trying-to-do-window-resize-with-jquery-cycle-slideshow - this post gives a simple bit of JS and CSS which seems to have taken care of the problem very efficiently :)

Comment: Embarrasingly I can't work out how to go to a new line on these comments without pressing return (which posts the comment) otherwise I'd write out the solution here :)

Comment: Just add an answer to your own question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else gets stuck on this - stackoverflow.com/questions/2183869/… - this post gives a simple bit of JS and CSS which seems to have taken care of the problem very efficiently :)